# Why does GROUP BY on table A cause "using temporary; using filesort" on table B?

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, group-by, explain

Given the following contrived example code:

```
SELECT      A.author_name
          , COUNT(T.title) AS num_titles

FROM        authors  A
JOIN        titles   T  ON  T.authorFK  =  A.authorPK

GROUP BY    A.authorPK
```

In `explain` the `Extra` column shows `Using temporary; Using filesort` alongside table `titles`.

If I delete the `COUNT` and the `GROUP BY`, Extra is now blank.

This is obviously a contrived simple example;  I can give a more real code sample, but I'm hoping someone knows what I'm talking about and can educate me based on this.  Thank you!

Using the current version of MariaDB.

Comment: Show complete CREATE TABLE for both tables and complete EXPLAIN output. Specify precise MariaDB versoin. Does `T.title` is nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Using temporary; Using filesort" is usually put on the first Explain line, regardless of which table needs them.
- There could be more than one "sort".  Use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to get this type of detail.
- The "file" in "filesort" does not necessarily mean that the sorting is done on disk.  When possible, it is actually done in RAM.
- `COUNT(T.title)` could probably be replaced by `COUNT(*)` and get the same result without checking `title` for being non-NULL.
- If an author might have zero titles, you won't see that from your query -- there will be no row for that author.  (Cf: `LEFT JOIN`)

Comment: Your first two points are very useful to me, ESPECIALLY the first one.  The amount of time I've tried to spend debugging indexes and not getting anywhere, and my confusion... all suddenly makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

What catches my eye with your sample query is "there is no WHERE clause".

That being the case, the query is basically doing a full join.

Even if `authorFK` is indexed in the `titles` table, the MySQL query optimizer  decided that doing `Using temporary; Using filesort` is better than trying to use the index in the join process. If your real query features `Using temporary; Using filesort` in the middle of the EXPLAIN plan, then "it is what is".

You could do one tangible thing without changing the query: increase [tmp_table_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and [max_heap_table_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) so that the temp table stays in RAM and not go to disk. This is contingent on your DB Server having enough RAM. This might help a simple query (such as the one you posted here), but may be counterintuitive if `Using temporary; Using filesort` appears multiple times in an EXPLAIN plan (implying more consumed RAM).

Also keep in mind that each JOIN clause that does not use an index creates an additional join buffer ([See join_buffer_size documentation paragraph 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size)). Thus, more RAM is still needed.

You may want to change the `JOIN` into a `LEFT JOIN`. EXPLAIN plan may still remain the same but might change performance.

I hope this gives you a start in improving your overall real query.

Comment: Sorry, the example query was just one I quickly tapped out to clarify the question in the title of the post - not a real query, not using a real schema or any real data.  Laziness on my part.  However, it did have the desired effect, I learnt something very important in Rick James's first bullet point.

Comment: Though your comments on tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size may also prove to be useful, as I have 128GB of RAM and not much knowledge on how to utilise it best!

Comment: Though they're both already 32GB.  mysqltuner hasn't suggested raising them either - I'll do some more reading.